Texture won't appear if not created directly before the draw command
I wrote a function to draw a rectangle and I want to add a texture. However, OpenGL can't apply it if it was initialized not in drawing function.
class Material {
public:

    Material(const char* filename) {
    
        int width, height, channels;
        unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &channels, STBI_rgb_alpha);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    ~Material() { release(); }

    Material(const Material &) = delete;
    Material &operator=(const Material &) = delete;

    Material(Material &&other) : texture(other.texture) {
        other.texture = 0; 
    }

    Material &operator=(Material &&other) {
        if(this != &other) {
            release();
            std::swap(texture, other.texture);
        }
    }

    GLuint texture = 0; 

private:

    void release() {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
        texture = 0;
    }
};

class SRender {
public:

    Material* mat = new Material("01.png");
    
    void drawRect () const;
};

float vertex[] = {0,0,0, 0,1,0, 1,1,0, 1,0,0};
float texCord[] = {0,0, 0,1, 1,1, 1,0};

void SRender::drawRect() const {
    
    //Material* mat2 = new Material("01.png");

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mat->texture);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCord);
    
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glPopMatrix();
}

#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION    
#include "stb_image.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;


    SRender render;


    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        "GLSample",
        "OpenGL Sample",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        256,
        256,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    while (!bQuit)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glPushMatrix();

            render.drawRect();

            glPopMatrix();

            SwapBuffers(hDC);

            Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}

If I use mat in glBindTexture, it draws a white rectangle, but if I use mat2 it works. I don't want to initialize it every time when I draw something. What is going wrong here?

The question cannot be answered because relevant code is missing in the question. Anyway, I assume that the SRender object is created before the OpenGL window and context are created. Since no OpenGL API function works without a current OpenGL context, the texture creation fails.

@Rabbid76 Thank you! I really created SRender before EnableOpenGL. Now it works. Sorry for bad example.

@Rabbid76 Well done spotting the problem! I think that the OpenGL window part was the problem, this looks like OpenGL 1.1 to me, so before the concept of an OpenGL context was introduced.

@Rabbid76 I now see that it's the "OpenGL rendering context" from Windows, not an "OpenGL context" as introduced in OpenGL 3.0.

@Yun This is completely irrelevant here. The problem is that an OpenGL API function is used before the OpenGL context is created and made current.

The SRender object is created before the OpenGL window and context are created. Since no OpenGL API function works without a current OpenGL context, the texture creation fails. The SRender object must be created after the OpenGL context has been made current with EnableOpenGL.
// SRender render;                <--- DELETE

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

SRender render;                 // <--- INSERT

